# ScrollView inside ConstraintLayout not working as expected

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

ScrollView inside ConstrainLayout seems not working like its normal behavior.
anyone facing/tried this type of xml design structure then please give suggestion.

Here is the xml file,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context=".fragment.HomeFragment">
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollview">

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the actual problem, as I checked on my side it is working fine

Comment: not scrolling in ConstraintLayout content.

Comment: @RajuTukadiya Can you please explain your use case, as in what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `<ScrollView>` tag to match the following:

> ```
> <ScrollView
>     android:id="@+id/scrollview"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:fillViewport="true"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cardview">
> ```

And add this `id` attribute to your `CardView`:

> ```
> <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>     android:id="@+id/cardview"
> ```

Without specifying a bottom constraint (and using `wrap_content` for the height), the `ScrollView` will size itself to be large enough that all of the content fits inside of it, but is clipped by the parent `ConstraintLayout`. If all the content fits, there's nothing to scroll (even though you can't see it all, since the parent is clipping it).